# How to get data from Oracle ERP

Tags: integration, oracle

Our company has some data (employee info) in Oracle ERP 11. Whereas on other hand we have SharePoint 2016. We want to create a responsive Org Chart fetching data from Oracle ERP.
Kindly let know which is the ideal way to do so. Any working sample / steps will be of great help.

Kindly let know if any further details required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read data from oracle DB in SharePoint via `Bussiness connectivity service` (BCS)

**Steps:**

1. Create a [database Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server.aspx) between SQL server and Oracle DB by installing `OLEDB` client on the SQL server only.
2. Use SharePoint designer to build an external content type for SQL server.Check the detail steps at [SharePoint: BCS Connect To Oracle DB No Code](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30887.sharepoint-2013-bcs-connect-to-oracle-db-no-code.aspx)

[image]

3. Now you have a SharePoint list and you can read and Create your Org Chart from it. like mentioned at [here](https://sharepointorgchart.com/how-to/creating-org-chart-list) and [here](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/create-organizational-chart-sharepoint-office-2013)